# Angular custom-control-input doesn't work correctly with formControlName inside loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, form-control

i want to apply a custom theme style on angular but checkbox didn't work correctly.

i have this part of code and worked very well :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of lists let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="field_check"  formControlName="checked">
                <label class="form-control-label"  for="field_check">check</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But when i try to add a custom class control not working :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of lists let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="field_check" formControlName="checked">
                <label class="custom-control-label"  for="field_check">check</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

how to apply my `class="custom-control-input"` without losing the `class="form-control"` ? i have already tried this `class="form-control custom-control-input"` but didn't work

**UPDATE**

after inspect element i found this :

[image: css]

so when here is the result i got :

[image: result]

i have no access to css code `custom-control-input` and `form-control how` can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work ideally, it is best if you can see which style is applying on control using inspect element. May be it is overrided by form-control class. You might have to use ! Important in class.

Comment: the style is applying is custom-control-input and everything working very well but the problem is that  all chackbox on the loop change only the first one .

Comment: that because [formGroupName]="i" not applying on  custom-control-input

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud hey did you find a solution to that, struggling with the same problem

Comment: @Avinash try to reproduce your problem in stackblitz and i will try to fix it with you !!